# iPhone7 mail is not updating

Tags: iphone, macbook-pro, mail.app

My iPhone7 (13.4.1) has suddenly stopped updating Mail (gmail).  So, I'm reading/editing/deleting mail on my MacBook Pro but my iPhone is displaying as 'unread' messages I have actually deleted from Mail on the MacBook.

This has not happened before (many months working fine) and I'm not aware of changing anything. Any suggestions please?

Comment: Have you tried verifying that all your accounts are signed into properly on your iPhone? You can check in Settings > Account and Passwords or if you go to mail, you will see a tiny "Account Error" at the bottom if that is the problem. Please edit your question to mention if your accounts are used for other iOS apps such as Calendar and whether those are experiencing issues.

Comment: Since Gmail is IMAP all of your mail, etc. is on the server. So delete the gmail account and re-add it. That usually does it for me.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions.  I thought the iPhone was the problem but it turns out that it was actually the MacBook that was not passing information to Gmail!  When I rebooted the MacBook the problem resolved.